# Using programming templates for large scale system

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a student of object oriented programming with C++ and slowly I am learning new things. 
As a part of my term presentation of my course I am asked to speak on a statement that states:

"Is using programming templates for development of large scale systems justified?"

I am given with the following article to study about software architecture of the large scale software system:

http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/publications/2001/RepresentingLargeScaleArchitecture.pdf

But after reading it I'm not able to decide whether templates should be adopted while developing such systems or should be avoided.

I'm familiar with basic concepts and run-time and compilation time scenarios using templates but for larger systems are there any complexities with using templates or use of templates is safe sailing in development of large system?

Kindly highlight reasons in either way whether template should be used to done away with.

Comment: This paper seems to operate on a higher level, agnostic of such implementation-details like templates. How is that related to your topic?

Comment: The paper just tells me about the architecture of large systems I suppose and after reading it I have to decide while coding for such I system should we use templates or not. There is not single word written in article about templates, for this reason its becoming difficult for me decide whether go with templates or not

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, and since the term "using programming templates" is rather curious, are you sure the question is asking about templates in the specific C++ generic programming construct sense, rather than in the more general sense of some kind of standardized starting point?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a decided maybe.  Seriously, it depend on what the
templates are being used for.  Templates have a significant cost in
added complexity and coupling.  The alternatives may also have
significant cost, however—when the cost of the alternatives is
higher than the cost of templates, then you use templates.  (This is
true regardless of the size of the application, of course.  But things
like added complexity and coupling tend to have a much greater impact in
large projects.)

Before addressing the question, you have to distinguish between using
templates, and defining templates.  There is certainly no argument
against using templates defined in the standard library, for example:
any added costs have been paid by the developers of the library, not by
you, so it's all benefits.  Similar arguments apply for third party 
libraries.  For templates you define yourself, however, you must
consider the impact that a modification in the template definition has
on build times.  Defining templates for just about everything is **not**
a good idea.  On the other hand, you might be able to isolate certain
functionalities, and treat them almost as you would a third party
library, developed in house, but not modified except in extreme cases.

Interestingly enough, where templates don't cause problems (low level,
very stable elements) is typically where they are most useful.  For
“application level” modules, which deal with the actual
application specific code, templates typically aren't too useful anyway;
inheritance is far more useful.  For low level components, along the
lines of `std::vector`, on the other hand, they're exceedingly useful;
but such components are generally developed in isolation from the rest
of the application, must be very stable anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much James, such a concrete and clarifying answer. 
Many thanks. =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not telling you the answer but I'll give you this hint.

Ask your self this:

What are the compelling reasons for using templates, and the compelling reasons for not using templates (like compile time)?

Then ask yourself why if any of these reasons are useful or detrimental in large scale systems?

Lets look at the large scale systems. What makes them large? It could be many things such as:

- Amount of code
- Number users
- scale of deployment
- geography
- cost of development
- cost of maintennance

  etc.

Now consider some things that templates are good for

- resuabilty and componentisation of algorithms

etc

How do these two aid the above?

- Amount of code : well resuabilty will help to reduce the amount of code to maintain
- Cost of development: resuabilty will help this too as there is less to develop, but it may increase cost if the developers need to be more skilled. So double edged sword there
- Cost of maintenance :  resuabilty will help here as there less to test and maintain

If you answer the first, the latter becomes much easier.

There is no right or wrong answer, rather it's an argument that each system's design will analyse and decide upon based on the actual concerns of the system in question.

Comment: You also have to consider trade-offs like higher compilation-times.

Comment: Well Preet templates offer both advantages and disadvantages, they may render poor portability of system, difficult maintenance, code bloat and things like that but on the same side they may offer many advantages as well. I am a student and I have not yet software industrial standards, that is why I am asking this question. If I had enough knowledge/experience then I would have decided myself and have not asked here to trouble you people. Hope you understand.

Comment: NO problems Alan - I've added to the answer.

Comment: Many thanks Preet.
Now I am in a better position to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is highly subjective, and I have the impression that you won't arrive to an answer that satisfies all large-scale system developers or even all your teachers. Personally, I go for the simpler way of doing something, and that sometimes means not-working-with-templates and sometimes means let-templates-replicate-the-code-for-you. Compilation times can always be firewalled with PIMPL or with explicit instantiations, but avoiding templates where their use would be only natural can incur in more bloating, obscure runtime errors and loss of performance.

My suggestion for your homework: present all the arguments favoring and countering the use of templates, and don't conclude with a yes-or-no answer, but rather with something in between ;-) . And don't let the zealots of software methodologies to take the joy of coding from you.

Comment: Lol
Yes my mind was also giving me a mixed answer "Both yes and no". 
And I suspect that finding an answer to this question would be like t take part in a race that will never end.